# C# Language Specification and Entry Point in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am reading the C# language specification; ECMA-334.

In the section "8.1 Application startup", it says that the entry point name should be `Main`. But in an ASP.NET MVC application, the entry point would be in `Global.asax` with the name `Application_Start`.

Does this mean that an ASP.NET MVC application is not an application but a class library?

Comment: ASP.NET websites **are** class libraries (you can check the project properties), not full programs. The real program that has a main method is the webserver process that host it.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are talking about "classic" asp.net (as in not .net core). 
It is indeed a class library and it's being hosted by IIS application pools (well, most of the time). Setting up IIS you will notice that it operates in terms of web applications - which is basically your entry point that it provides for you along with all the plumbing.

You can have a [self-hosted asp.net application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api) but I believe you must have a good use case if you go that route

Comment: Yes. asp classic. I noticed that Core has a "Main". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The surest way to answer your question is to look into PE.

The second section of PE headers is the File Header, it contains several bits info and one of them in is the [Characteristics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#characteristics).

> The Characteristics field contains flags that indicate attributes of the object or image file.

One of the flags is 0x2000

> The image file is a dynamic-link library (DLL). Such files are considered executable files for almost all purposes, although they cannot be directly run.

So to know if your file is an executable or a dynamic-link library, just check this bit. If it set to 1 is DLL if it set to 0 is executable.
To examine the PE (without code) you have several options, for example check CFF Explorer or dnSpy.

(in your case you will see that this flag is set to 1)

One more interesting this you can check is the EntryPointToken inside .NET Directory (don't confuse with AddressOfEntryPoint in the Optional Header).

Answer (score -1):

Project Type and their Entry Point

**1. .NetFramework ConsoleApp :**

```
 *Static Void Main(string args[]){}*
```

**2. .NetCore App :**

```
 *Static Void Main //When you execute `dotnet new`*
```

**3. ASP.NET/ASP WebAPI :**

```
   *Constructor of HttpApplication class*
```

*ASP.NET automatically binds application events to handlers in the Global.asax file Application_Start and/or Application_BeginRequest*

**4. WPF:**

```
*App.Xaml overriden Method OnStartUp*
//Main method is autogenerated and is present in App.g.i.cs file located in App.Xaml.cs
//To override this behavior change Build type of App.Xaml from AppDefinition to Page
```

**5. WINForms**

```
*Static Void Main(string args[]){}* //Program.cs
```

**6. With DLLs**

```
 *[DllImport("DllName", EntryPoint = "Functionname")]*
 //Dlls do not have an entry point, the EntryPoint attribute above ensures that the the .NET runtime knows which function to call from the DLL being invoked
```

**P.S**

> There can only be one entry point in a C# program. If you have more
>   than one class that has a Main method, you must compile your program
>   with the /main compiler option to specify which Main method to use as
>   the entry point.

**Reference:**

LifeCycleOverview of ASP.NET:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178473(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/

Comment: For WPF it is not true... The actual entry point of a WPF application is the Main method of the App class... This class is partial and the main method is generated on a separate file not shown in Visual Studio by default usually called App.g.i.cs.  Also you can just add your own program.cs file and set the entry point in the Properties of the project.  OnStartup is merely an event.

Comment: Also those are just "default" entry points.  You can just specify your won if you want.